# How would I find what specific wavelength I need to measure for a specific chemical in spectrophotometry (calcium perchlorate)?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, concentration, spectrophotometry, light

I am currently doing a research project, and for it, I would like to use a photospectrometer to find the concentration of Calcium Perchlorate in my sample solutions. My current method of data collection relies on using an indicator (methalyne blue) to form a purple precipitate to observe under a microscope as a qualitative means to collect data, but if I can use a spectrophotometer (96 well) to directly measure absorbance and in turn concentration, that wold be heavily preferred.

How would I be able to find out what specific wavelength I need to measure for my Calcium Perchlorate? I can't find any preexisting values online for Calcium Perchlorate, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Apparently, calcium perchlorate is a yellow-white crystalline solid, so just prepare a solution at some reasonable concentration and run a UV-Visible absorbance scan from 200 nm to 900 nm. If you get absorbances that are very small, use a higher concentration.

Comment: @EdV, seems like a good answer, why not make it one?

Comment: @Snijderfrey Nothing particularly insightful, frankly: if the OP has the instrument available, it is an easy thing to try. I did a little searching and evidently the IR might be better for this one. The yellow tint, though, might indicate a usable absorbance either side of yellow. Apparently, this chemical might exist on Mars, so that would be cool. If you want to write up an answer, go for it!

Comment: @edV funny you say that! i'm actually doing an experiment on phytoremediation of calcium perchlorate concentrations seen on potential human Mars landing zones :).

Comment: @EdV sorry I didn't realize that's return comments on mobile, but i'm definitely gonna give it a shot in the upcoming days, thank you so much for the insight, it really helps!